# How to write a query for a shared/footer.html.eex?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have a shared footer which I show display on all the pages, almost. I want to display some information from a database in it. Instead of querying it in each action of my webapplication accross all the controller and passing it via assigns in each action in each controller, is there any way to query it once in some kind of action for footer?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consider creating a controller plug which would allow you to assign the footer information in any number of controllers and actions. You would then have something like the following in your controllers.

```
plug :assign_footer when action in [:index, :show, :edit]
```